# Java comparator for sorting double-nested generics array

Tags: java, sorting, generics

With Java 17 I want to compare map entries based upon some criteria, where the map entries are Java classes associated with some value, like this:

```java
Comparator<Map.Entry<Class<?>, Integer>> MY_COMPARATOR =
    new Comparator<Map.Entry<Class<?>, Integer>>() { … }
```

Later I have a list of a list of classes and their associated values (whether it's counts, memory size, or whatever). The twist is that my code is so refined (tongue in cheek) that I happen to know that all these classes extend from `FooBar`:

```java
List<Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>, Integer>> foobarValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I just want to sort those map entries using `MY_COMPARATOR` (to find the smallest/largest classes, the classes most encountered, or whatever `MY_COMPARATOR` uses as its criteria). But this doesn't work:

```java
java.util.Collections.sort(foobarValues, MY_COMPARATOR);
```

Java (actually Eclipse 2022-09) tells me:

> `The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>,Integer>>, Comparator<Map.Entry<Class<?>,Integer>>)`

I've been working with Java generics for a long time, and my best simplified explanation of what's happening is that the `? super T` in `Collections.sort()` "hides" the lower layer of generics, and that `? super Map.Entry<Class<?>>` has no relation to `? super Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>>`. (But still, really?.) Actually my mind can't quite grasp the full intricacies of the problem.

But let's say I don't care so much about the problem; I just want the code to work with no warnings. You and I know that the comparator can work with *any class that is possible to exist*, so it will never cause a `ClassCastException` and it will never cause heap pollution, and it will never even sneak into your house at night and kill your bamboo plant.

How can I tell Java that it's OK for me to use this comparator? This does not work:

```java
Collections.sort(foo, (Comparator<Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>, Integer>>)MY_COMPARATOR);
```

I would be happy casting the list being sorted, but this doesn't work either:

```java
Collections.sort((List<Map.Entry<Class<?>, Integer>>)foo, MY_COMPARATOR);
```

This *does* work!

```java
Collections.sort(foo, (Comparator<Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>, Integer>>)(Object)comparator);
```

But to use it I have to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, and Java 17 `javac` with `-Xlint:all` still complains, and besides I feel dirty using it.

I would be content with some workaround that would allow me to suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` as long as javac lint still didn't complain. But the intermediate cast to `Object` is too much of a kludge for me to accept.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Your List is of type `...Class<? extends FooBar>...` but the comparator is simply `...Class<?>...`, as you saw. The casting further on in your question essentially confirms that is the issue. Why not define your `Comparator` as `<? extends FooBar>` to begin with?

Comment: @Rogue Probably because the comparator isn't specific to comparing map entries that have `Class<? extends FooBar>` as keys.

Comment: I suppose that's fair, but I'm pretty sure the language semantics for generics will bite you in that case (nested generics don't play very well here). From my understanding, a `Foo<A<? extends X>>` and a `Foo<A<? extends Y>>` (unrelated A/B/X/Y classes) are just as different as `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` for this kind of type inference resolution.

Comment: `MY_COMPARATOR` can work with any class in the world. Why should I constrain it to `FooBar` classes? And my list is really `List<Map.Entry<Class<? extends T>, Integer>>`, as it itself is parameterized in a captured generic type, so I don't even know what type it is ahead of time. But why should I care what type of class it is? I know `MY_COMPARATOR` can handle it! And yes, the "language semantics for generics [are] bit[ing] [me] in [this] case". The question is: we all agree this should work and no harm will come from it. And it's even logical. So how do I work around it?

Comment: I'll even be happy with a small kludge that I can suppress warnings on, but intermediate casting to `Object` is too much I think. Plus it still leaves warnings.

Comment: Change your declaration to `Comparator<Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>> MY_COMPARATOR …` There is, by the way, no need to resort to `Collections.sort(…)` anymore. You can simply call `foobarValues.sort(MY_COMPARATOR);`

Comment: Wow, Holger, that did it!! (You don't know how many combinations of `extends` and `super` I tried. ) Please place your comment in a separate answer; I want to open a bounty to award it and show my appreciation. And thanks for reminding me about `List.sort()`. Yes, this is super-old code I'm trying to finally clean up. (One comment in that file said, "works on Eclipse 3.4M3 but not on Sun JDK 1.6.0_03-b05", so it was a while ago. )

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you declare the comparator by applying the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) principle. It should have the type:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>>
```

Both type parameters for `Map.Entry` should have `? extends` (though just the first one is enough to fix the error) because a map entry is a producer of its keys and value types.

You could also add `? super` to the type parameter of `Comparator`, since the comparator is a consumer of map entries, but that is not needed here because it is actually already written in the method signature of `sort`.

```
void sort(Comparator<? super E> c)
```

After that, you can write:

```
foobarValues.sort(MY_COMPARATOR);
```

---

If you cannot change the type of `MY_COMPARATOR`, one way to get the compiler to "just shut up" is to cast to `Object` first:

```
(Comparator<Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>, Integer>>) (Object) MY_COMPARATOR
```

Casting from `Object` to a parameterised type is an unchecked cast, which is presumably what you are looking for.

This unchecked cast would be safe as far as I know, since a map entry cannot be used as a consumer of its key type. You can only get, but not set, its key.

Comment: Holger had mentioned this as well, and indeed `Comparator<Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>>` works! I'm grateful for the answer! I had went over the PECS principle, but in my mind that would give me `Comparator<? extends Map.Entry<Class<?>, Integer>>`. I'll have to say I'm a 90% expert on Java generics, but that last 10% is a doozy! haha

Comment: @GarretWilson See my edit. `Comparator` is a consumer here, not a producer!

Comment: Gah, good catch. Even with PECS in mind, I glossed over applying `extends` on `Class`.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that `sort(Comparator<? super E>)` is the same as my using `Comparator<? super Map.Entry<Class<?>>`? So in this case, the `? extends Class<?>` is functioning as a _producer_ to the `Map.Entry<>`, while `Comparator<>` is functioning as a _consumer_ to `sort()`? 

Comment: I mean **if** `sort` were only declared to take `Comparator<E>`, you would have to apply PECS at the `Comparator` level and write `Comparator<? super ...>` too. Since it's declared to take `Comparator<? super E>`, you don't have to do that, but it's fine if you do. `Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>` reads "`Map.Entry` is a producer of `Class<?>`" and `sort(Comparator<? super E>)` reads "`sort` takes in a comparator, that is a consumer of `E`s". I think you should go through the PECS post again... @GarretWilson

Comment: @GarretWilson a common source of confusion is that types like `Map.Entry<Class<?>, Integer>` and `Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>, Integer>` are *invariant*. The type arguments are types with wildcards, but the generic type (here `Map.Entry<…>`) has no wildcards. So neither of those types is a subtype of the other. But both are subtypes of `Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>` (which is a type with wildcards). So, if the comparator can sort elements of type `Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>`, it can also sort elements of the subtype `Map.Entry<Class<? extends FooBar>, Integer>`…

Comment: "So neither of those types is a subtype of the other." Yeah, I was getting that part. But … oh, I think I see: you've made `Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, Integer>` a more general class by making the second level of generics non-specific. `Map.Entry<X, Integer>` isn't a subtype of `Map.Entry<Y, Integer>`, but by saying `Map.Entry<? extends Z, Integer>` you take the type compatibility problem away at that level by making that level not a specific type. Something like that. It's hard to explain in simple words, but I think intuitively I understand. Thank you.